# XSD Schema diagram using Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, emf

Eclipse has an XML perspective which is handy for developing XML and XML Schemas (XSD).
One nice this is that it allows you to create a diagram(png) of the schema, however it seems to only do one level at a time.
My XSD contains a number of complex types each type may refer to one or more complex sub-types, I just want a nice diagram of the entire (from top level to the bottom level) structure.
Any ideas of how to do this in Eclipse?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have installed EMF (Eclipse Modeling Framework), you can do the following to create a diagram of your XSD.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Finish by double clicking the text which says to double click.. then you end up with a diagram of the XSD.
[image]